# How to check specific index of a character in stringbuilder

Tags: c#

I have a string builder:-

```
StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
```

I have to check, if this string builder has empty values from position 26 to position 208.

Comment: You can just loop through the string

Comment: Can I use IndexOf or SubString ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this hope this one work for you.

```
StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder()
st = st.ToString(26,182); --- first parameter use for start position and second use for length.
if(st.Contains("search text"))
{

}
```

Comment: Converting tostring is a overhead here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ! Works for me :)

```
var hasSpace = Enumerable.Range(0, st.Length).Any(index => st[index] == ' ');
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**